# Relay is switching but no power?

Tags: raspbian

I am using a SainSmart relay and I am using it with my 3d printer to switch it on and off. I am just using it to switch the power on after the power supply so it's only working with 12v.i have everything working the way it should and the relays are clicking and the led for each relay is turning on and off like it should. The problem is when I check the terminals on the relay with a meter I see the 12v coming in but when the relay switches neither of the other two terminals show power. The wires are connected as follows

Relay               RPi3

Vcc                    3.3v

Jd-vcc              5v

Gnd                 Gnd on both the RPi3 and printer ground

In1-4                 gpio 16,18 I am only using 2

The relay has three terminals and I have tried switching the power wire coming in and the one coming out to the items I am trying to power with no luck. I am very new to all of this so please take it easy on me. I am using Octoprint to control the relay so I know the code works it is as easy as just choosing the correct gpio.

Comment: Add a photo of your wiring to your question.

Comment: Just a note on the three terminals on a general purpose relay: They are labelled **normally open (NO)**, **normally closed (NC)**, **common(C)** ... when the relay is not activated, there should be a connection between the NC and the C terminals.  When the relay is activated, there should be a connection between the NO and the C terminals... If [this](http://www.microcenter.com/product/437842/2-Channel_5V_Relay_Module) is your board... the NC terminal the one connected on the far side of the *looped* lines on the board... the common is the middle... and the NO is the single line.

Comment: Yeah I was aware of the terminals and how the relay works. I just didn't understand why they weren't working and if maybe I wasn't grasping how they would work with a Raspberry. They started working after a rewired them for the 5th or 6th time. Thanks for the help.